# Adding mounted device to file search

Tags: unity-dash

When I do file search in Unity, it only searches for fles in the drive in which Ubuntu is installed and not other drives. How to add different drives to it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think this is a better answer than what I gave:

[How can I search for files in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41829/how-can-i-search-for-files-in-unity)

I don't think this ppa made into 11.10 but this looks to be the way to go:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/real-files-folders-search-unity-lens.html

Given that the drive is mounted, you would enter the mount point into the configuration file and do the setuid that it recommends and you should be indexing those files as well.